# Book/book series where the main character's mind is copied into different alien clones

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, clones

Published no later than the mid-nineties, this science fiction story follows a man (possibly named Daniel or David?) who has his consciousness copied into a clone body modified to be of an alien species (or it could've been a real alien body with its mind wiped?).

Each part/chapter/book of the story follows a different clone/alien as they do whatever they were sent to do (I don't recall the reason for this; espionage, I imagine?).

One of the last clones/aliens is reptilian.

At the end (?) of the story, all the clones meet up with the original (assumed human?) character in what I vaguely remember as a shadowy meeting room with a round table and harsh lighting (that might be too much *The X-Files* filtering through though).

I originally read this book in grade 3 or 4 in my school's library, so it may have been aimed at young adults, but I recall the book(s) having a fairly mature/dark feel (it was the nineties, after all. Everything had to be edgy).

Comment: See if anything here looks familiar (warning! tvtropes link!) https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/CloningBlues/Literature

Comment: The description doesn't really match, but for some reason, Chalker's _Four Lords of the Diamond_ series came to mind...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be Jack Chalker's [Four Lords of the Diamond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Lords_of_the_Diamond) series:

> The Warden Diamond is a system of four planets, ruled by their own
> lords, collectively called "The Four Lords of the Diamond". Each
> planet of the Diamond has its own special "Warden Organism", a
> symbiotic microorganism that lives within the inhabitants of the
> planets. The organisms destroy their host when he or she leaves the
> Warden Diamond, making the planet system the ideal prison colony for
> the Confederacy, a massive space empire.
>
> An android clone that successfully infiltrated a government facility
> on a central world and downloaded vital defense information, transmits
> the information to a source and is destroyed in the process. The
> Confederacy discovers and tracks the clone towards the Warden Diamond,
> whose four lords are cooperating with an alien race to plan a mutiny
> against the Confederacy.
>
> The government sends its best agent to investigate. **Through
> technological advances, the government duplicates the personality of
> the agent (who remains unnamed throughout the series) and implants
> "him" into four brain-dead host bodies.** The four hosts are then sent
> to four different planets in the Warden system and have no choice but
> to fulfill their assignment of locating and defeating each of the Four
> Lords, delaying the expected alien invasion and finding out vital
> information on the infiltrators.

Comment: This definitely _feels_ like the right series, I don't see any reference to the lizard form in the plot summaries I have found, but that may have been mis-remembered.

Comment: Charon: A Dragon at the Gate (book 3) features a transformation into a lizard-man form.